# Generate white noise image in C#

Tags: c#, algorithm, image-processing

I need to be able to generate a white noise image in C# code. Is there an algorithm I can use to fill the image with white noise?

I have found the VB example of how to do it [here](http://iceyboard.no-ip.org/projects/white_noise_generator/), but I can't port it to .net myself.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Should be something very simple along these lines, no?

```
foreach(var pixel in image)
{
    pixel = rand()>0.5 ? white : black;
}
```

Comment: As far as I can tell this is the algorithm being used in that link

Comment: @Justin Yeah at a glance it doesn't look like anything but random bit noise. I suppose it might be doing something special but I didn't download the zip to check.

Answer (score 10):

[White Noise](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/White_noise) is not black or white (per definition). It contains also grayscales.

So we are already closer with:

```
foreach(var pixel in image) 
{
  //do that for all RGB (depending on Image format)
  pixel = rand() * 255;
}
```

[image: white noise]

Comment: I agree, but the imagine in the link is not using grayscale, its binary b&w.

Comment: i was hesitating too (its not from me, its wikipedia) but with high zoom mode youc an see quite well that it contains grayscales.

Comment: Your example certainly does, and your correct that real whitenoise is more then just black and white. The link in the question though, seems to just be generating black and white random noise images.