# Second instance of ffmpeg for experimenting

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I'm experimenting with databending/glitching images and videos as part of a master's class. I've used [Audacity to do most of it](http://www.hellocatfood.com/databending-using-audacity/) thus far, but it isn't as successful with video.

I want to try to edit video by changing the source codecs in `ffmpeg`, but I don't want to inadvertently destroy my current install.

**Is it possible to install a second instance of ffmpeg to run independently for experimentation purposes?**

If so, what Terminal command would I use to create a second, executable directory?

Comment: This is not very clear. Do you mean to compile a modified version of ffmpeg ? If so, you can just rename the executable into my-ffmpeg, or something.

Comment: which OS are you on?

Comment: OSX 10.9. Sorry...should have put that in the question. @SirDarius I need to change the source (the h.264 source, ex), which is why I'm making sure I know what I'm doing. Will renaming the executable create a copy of the sources as well? (I hope this makes sense...)

Comment: No. You download the ffmpeg source code, and the source code of its dependencies, like libx264, compile the whole thing. You're gonna obtain a shiny new `ffmpeg` binary which you can then rename to your liking.

Comment: As for image glitching some of the examples in [How to create video and audio noise with `ffmpeg`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15795112/1109017) may interest you.