# Simulate packet loss in internet video streaming

Tags: matlab, video, ffmpeg, noise

I have encoded H.264 video using FFmpeg. I want to apply packet loss model like Gilbert Eliot model to depict video transmission over unreliable network.[Like in this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15792105/simulating-tv-noise)  TV noise is simulated. But noise on the internet is different. So is there a way to simulate packet loss/ noise for internet video streaming using FFmpeg or MATLAB?

Comment: Can you provide a link to a video that displays the effect you want to re-create?

Comment: @LordNeckbeard Thanks for commenting.The video is simple foreman sequence . Like you answered in the thread that simulate TV noise. i have applied that command but my area is to apply RTP packet loss and want to recover the loss on decoder end using FEC. I want to know is there a way to simulate internet noise or RTP packet loss in FFmpeg?

Comment: I guess the best method would be to actually stream it and initiate RTP packet loss somehow. I'm not sure if it is possible to fake it with `ffmpeg` because I don't know what it is supposed to look like.

Comment: @LordNeckbeard using JM could be the way?  Also if i want to recover lost packets  what techniques are available in FFmpeg?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using [Netem](http://www.linuxfoundation.org/collaborate/workgroups/networking/netem). It's part of Linux traffic control and you can create any type of delay, jitter and loss you want.