# How to apply light noise on video?

Tags: ffmpeg

I have seen this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15792105/simulating-tv-noise) about applying noise using FFMPEG on video

I have seen the video of [Megamind.avi](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/samples/data/Megamind.avi) and it noisy version [Megamind_bugy.avi](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/samples/data/Megamind_bugy.avi)

I want to apply the same noise on my list of video as well

I need help, I need the command to get the same noise, I'm using ffmpeg in ubuntu

thank you

Comment: Those are closer to decoding glitches - look up datamoshing.

Comment: @cht_usr If you want to use `ffmpeg`, the noise bitstream filter is your best bet to get an effect like that. It is mentioned in the link you provided, but YMMV.